# IP address changes when requested

Tags: iis-7, website

I am trying to troubleshoot a situation where the URL of my website will change from the domain (www.example.com) to the IP address (192.0.2.1) (not the real IP address) when you browse from page to page. It is an IIS server.

I don't really have a clue on where to start, I've been googling for the last few weeks and thought i would give this a try.

The tricky thing is I cant recreate the problem regularly so this makes narrowing the problem down very difficult.

Where it is happening: 
I'm running a image slider called [NinjaSlider](http://www.menucool.com/responsive-slider) and when the IP address changes it shows all the trial version text. I've paid for a lic and contacted the developers and said it wasn't the code and has something to do with the server or its settings.

Comment: Do you run some sort of CMS that does redirection? Does it happen on all pages? The real domain could really help the troubleshooting process

Comment: No Cms, Just on the image slider. Added more to see if it's more clear.

Comment: Check all files in the sites physical path for the IP address with grep or 'find in files' from a text editor.

Also you could try linking the website. Somebody may find the issue.

Comment: Linking the site would potentially cost me my job because we are such a small team.  @Dylan Knoll you sir might have just fixed my problem. Will get back to you on this.